# Iframe height [dynamic] for every 2 second

Tags: javascript, html, css

my problem is when I load iframe it's set height of iframe correctly and also when data(content) load in iframe it;s automatically set height ,BUT when page load in iframe and set height relatively page content and then if I reduce or delete content from loaded page it will not reduce iframe height.(e.g when page load first time height set `100px` and dynamically load data on page iframe height set to `150px` and when I reduce data it's not set height of iframe it remain `150px`). This is my code:

```
function setIframeHeight(iframe) {
    if (iframe) {
        var iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.parentWindow;
        if (iframeWin.document.body) {
            iframe.height = iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight || iframeWin.document.body.scrollHeight;
        }
        setInterval("setIframeHeight_id('" + iframe.id + "')", 2000);
    }
    return false;
}

function setIframeHeight_id(iframeid) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(iframeid);
    if (iframe) {
        var iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.parentWindow;
        if (iframeWin.document.body) {
            iframe.height = iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight || iframeWin.document.body.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function resizeIframe(nm) {
    setIframeHeight(document.getElementById(nm));
}
```

HTML

```
 <iframe id="IframeData" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" onload="resizeIframe('IframeData')" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest you to use jQuery instead of plain JavaScript. It won't do a miracle by itself, but will sure help you shorten your code.

When it comes to your problem, why not using percentage sizes instead of fixed pixel size? Let's say your iframe's height is set to `100%`, instead of `150px`. By doing this way, next time you resize the parent container, the iframe itself will stretch to parent's height.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thnx for your replay,, but my code is given value as pixel(iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight) and it will calculate height if iframe regarding  contant of loded page in iframe.and i draw your attention that 100% not work on iframe content issue.